# Tag synonym: lan-party -> lan

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't see any reason why we need separate tags for [lan-party](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan-party) and [lan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag merging taken care of, kind sir.

Answer (score -2):

[lan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan) Should mean gaming over a lan connection, which may or may not be local anymore these days (see [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29)).

[lan-party](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan-party) should refer to the actual venue of hosting a party that involves PC gaming, which may not even be over a lan connection (see [The Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_internet)). However, lan party retains its name due to the original technology it was founded on.

Although I don't see many questions about lan parties, I do believe they are in scope and should not be merged. I request undoing the tag merge.

Comment: I disagree - "lan party" has a very specific meaning, referring to gaming together with multiple people in one physical location.  Whether those joined people are playing on a server on the internet is irrelevant: whether the problem relates to their internal network ([tag:lan]) or it relates to their connection ([tag:multiplayer]), [tag:lan-party] is redundant

Comment: @DaveMcClelland I don't understand how your disagreeing. Lan is clearly a technology and Lan-party is clearly a social medium.

Comment: I agree with you the two are distinct. I'm not sure "lan party" deserves a tag, though. It is better addressed by either "lan" - if asking a technical question about the technology involved - or "multiplayer" for other issues relating to lan parties.

Comment: @Oak I'm okay with that, perhaps instead lan-party should be merged into multiplayer.

Comment: @Resorath Anyone questions tagged with lan-party will almost certainly refer to problems with the local (physical) network.  If not, it's mistagged.  If it *is* related to a local network issue, then [tag:lan] covers it